# Using MathContext objects in BigDecimal divide method

Tags: java, javascript, bigdecimal

I am writing test cases with the [JavaScript BigDecimal library by Daniel Trebbien](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js) (specifically the *BigDecimal-all-last.min.js*) and I can't seem to use the MathContext object in the divide method without throwing the error *"MathContext() Bad form value"*

Since this library is a direct port from Java, I am using [this documentation](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/ibm/icu/math/MathContext.html). Since both the "form" (parameter #2) and "rounding mode" (parameter #4) are just constants, I don't understand why I am getting a "bad form value" error.  My Webstorm IDE sees the constants just fine so I know they are there.  Changing "form" constants to "ENGINEERING" or any of the others does not fix the issue.

```
var mc = new MathContext(3, BigDecimal.PLAIN, false, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
var two = new BigDecimal("2");
var seven = new BigDecimal("7");
var twoSevenths = two.divide(seven, mc); // constructor divide(BigDecimal, MathContext)
console.log(twoSevenths.toString()); // expecting 0.286
```

Do you see anything I am doing wrong?

**

### UPDATE

There ARE other divide constructors one could use of course, but the multiple re-use of a single MathContext object would be ideal for a Tiny JavaScript project and thus is the focus here.

**

Comment: Are you doing Java or JavaScript?

Comment: Daniel's library is a direct port from Java to JavaScript. The test code above is JavaScript.

Comment: Oh Lord!  Did I just ask a question that is going to earn the "Tumbleweed badge"?  lol  Would have thought a BigDecimal pro would have seen an error by now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small typo in your code. The `PLAIN` constant is actually defined in `MathContext`, so the first line should be:

```
var mc = new MathContext(3, MathContext.PLAIN, false, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
```

With this fix, "0.286" is logged to the console as expected.

Comment: Thanks Bro - I see I relied on the WebStorm IDE too much here.

Comment: If this helps anyone else, note that your IDE software may incorrectly display that constants like PLAIN and ROUND_HALF_EVEN are members of other classes (like BigDecimal). This seems to stem from the fact that they are all declared in the same .js file (which is how we like minified files to be of course). In Java this is not an issue but JavaScript IDE's are not as robust generally speaking.